# jQuery datetimepicker used for range

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to set up a 2 datetime pickers to select a range. But I keep getting strange behaviour. I get flickering on the time selectors and when I select one and then the other the first field gets its time removed. I'm following the [example here](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/#range_examples)

```
 dateSelectorStart.datetimepicker({
     dateFormat: sos.kvp.i18n.dateFormat.datePicker,
     maxDate: 0,
     onClose: function(dateText, inst){
         if(dateSelectorEnd.val() != ''){
             var startDate = dateSelectorStart.datetimepicker('getDate');
             var enddate = dateSelectorEnd.datetimepicker('getDate');
             if(startDate > enddate){
                 dateSelectorEnd.datetimepicker('setDate',startDate);
             }
         } else {
             dateSelectorEnd.val(dateText);
         }
    },
    onSelect: function(selectedDateTime){
         dateSelectorEnd.datetimepicker('option','minDate',dateSelectorStart.datetimepicker('getDate'));
    }
});

dateSelectorEnd.datetimepicker({
    dateFormat: sos.kvp.i18n.dateFormat.datePicker,
    maxDate: 0,
    onClose: function(dateText, inst){
        if(dateSelectorStart.val() != '') {
            var startDate = dateSelectorStart.datetimepicker('getDate');
            var enddate = dateSelectorEnd.datetimepicker('getDate');
            if(startDate > enddate){
                dateSelectorStart.datetimepicker('setDate',enddate);
            }
        } else {
            dateSelectorStart.val(dateText);
        }
    },
    onSelect: function(selectedDateTime){
        dateSelectorStart.datetimepicker('option','maxDate',dateSelectorEnd.datetimepicker('getDate'));
    }
});
```

EDIT:

I have narrowed it down, the problem comes from setting the option minDate and MaxDate.

Comment: can u provide fiddle or something?

Comment: I would but i dont know how to use jFiddle :D

Comment: ohh .. if can add code here to tht also work...

Comment: I verified you code and it not having any issue with plugin.. might there will be other jS issue